# Using single "init" of libcurl in C to retrieve data from server

Tags: c, client-server, libcurl

I am using libcurl in C to retrieve data from a server. I am caching the initial connection to be used again and again for further retrieving from the server. But, i also want the GET or POST question to be asked each time I ask for a response from the server.. Any workaround this?

Comment: So you want the connection to be kept alive even between requests - doesn't libcurl do that already? (if you don't init several times)

Comment: yes, but i also want to be asked whether the request is GET or POST each time i ask for data from the server..can u help me with this?

Comment: Hmm sorry I don't understand - hopefully someone smarter might have something more helpful to say.

Comment: when you use curl_init, while execution, we would be asked whether the request to be sent is in GET or POST form, this is asked only once during the initiation. I would like to call this each time i send a request to the server.

Comment: try understanding this if possible, and thanks very much for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "workaround" needed, you simply set the correct options for each transfer you want and libcurl will use GET or POST correctly. It will still reuse the connection if you reuse the curl handle and the server doesn't close it...

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) is a common option to set POST (with data) and then you reset it back to use GET with [CURLOPT_HTTPGET](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPGET.html).

Comment: okay thank you very much..
will check too see if its satisfying my need.